# redirect ajax requests

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

i want redirect **ALL** ajax requests(with X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest in header) to action: `ajax(string function, string args)` . How can i do it?

For example: browser send ajax query with paramerts function=getImage&args=4 to url http://localhost/post/123 but we redirect query to http://localhost/ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom route and/or route constraint.

Look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like Server.Transfer() would work best